# What am I doing wrong when I post a comment with an at-symbol reference to another user?

Tags: support, comments

Here: [When to call asynchronous QMenu::popup() vs synchronous QMenu::exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303201/when-to-call-qmenupopup-vs-qmenuexec)

I posted a comment on two different answers.  It seems like my `@` syntax to reference another user did not work correctly -- as I recall from previous SO behaviour.  What am I doing wrong?  (Smells like a face-palm!)

Help says: `To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.`

I tried to search Meta about this issue, but didn't find anything.  If this question is a dupe, please kindly comment, then vote to close!

Comment: What does  *did not work correctly* mean?

Comment: @rene When I view my comment, there seems to be no special highlighting or linking.  I think I know my issue: You can only "reply" (reference) a user in the *same* answer.  I think I misunderstand the at-symbol feature.  Also, typing this comment, I noticed when I type `@rene`, there is some type-ahead hinting.  I did not see on the two comments referenced in this question.  As I understand at-symbol user references, this adds a notification to the user's account.

Comment: The @-mention only works on the same *post*, where *post* can either be an *question* or an *answer*. So you can't under an answer @-mention a user that commented on your question. Or @-mention the OP of another answer.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @rene Perfect.  Should I close this question?  I am not sure how meta likes to handle this...

Comment: If the FAQ I linked you to answers your question then I'm happy to hammer your question closed.

Comment: @rene Yes please!  My first... `:-)`